# Finding the GCD of two polynomials.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Hello I'm trying to find the gcd of these two polynomials:

$$x^4-x^3-4x^2-x+5$$ $$x^2+x-2$$

And then I want to express the gcd of these two polynomials in terms of themselves multiplied by other polynomials (Like Bezout's lemma.)

I am struggling to do this though and would like so help. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to apply the euclidean algorithm to polynomials using polynomial long division?

Comment: Yes, the main reason I'm stuck is because there is a coefficient that isn't one when you do the long division? And I thought a GCD had to be monic so that's  why I'm getting confused.

Comment: @Sean, I think you should show your work using the Euclidean Algorithm in your question.

Comment: If $P$ is a common divisor, so is $\lambda P$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. You can thus simly scale your result to be monic. Maybe you should show your steps. You may want to use `\begin{align*}a^2+b^2 &= c^2 \\ d^2 + e^2 &= f^2\end{align*}` for better alignment when doing that: $$\begin{align*}a^2+b^2 &= c^2 \\ d^2 + e^2 &= f^2\end{align*}$$

Comment: So at one point I got the remainder to be $-5X+5$ so when I do the next division could I just divide by $-X+1$?

Comment: @Sean You can just continue with $-5X+5$. Only when you have the result of the algorithm, you should normalize it.

Comment: I would show my working but I'm not really sure how to format it properly for this site unfortunately.

Comment: Okay this gives me an answer of $-X+1$ as my GCD? Can anyone verify this. Then presumably I can just work back for the second part.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^4-x^3-4x^2-x+5$, $g(x)=x^2+x-2$

For $g(x)$, as $g(1)=0$,

$g(x)=(x-1)(x+2)$

For $f(x)$, observe

$f(1)=1-1-4-1+5=0$, so $(x-1)$ is a factor of $f(x)$, by the Remainder Theorem.

Hence $f(x)=(x-1)(x^3-4x-5)$.

For $h(x)=x^3-4x-5$,

Since $h(2)=8-8-5=-5\neq0$

$x-2$ obviously cannot divide $x^3-4x-5$ and they have no common factor.

So the GCD of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ is $x-1$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Division algorithm to divide the first by the second and keep going until we get zero remainder. The last we divided by is the gcd. Then we go back step by step. to express gcd as a linear combination.